Different simulation speeds between Python controller and C++ controller in Webots
I am working on a project in which i want to use Reinforcement Learning to fly the Crazyflie drone. To do this, i need the webots simulation to run as fast as possible.
I managed to create a python controller that can run at very high speed (the simulation is sped up to x300). The problem is that if i use the same controller but written in C++, the maximum simulation speed is x4.
The thing is that i need to use a C++ Library, so i can't just use my Python controller.
I am missing something or is this the normal behaviour of the simulator ?
Thanks for your answers

There are the following reasons why one configuration may run slower than another:

The Python version is configured to use GPU (you use machine learning); the C++ version is not properly configured. This would fully explain the difference.
The Python version's C++ layer (which is definitely there) is built with some switches to better support your CPU. More recent CPUs have additional commands that may greatly impact performance. Your C++ version may not use them, especially if you installed a pre-compiled package.
Some settings (resolution, frame rate, computation accuracy, number of iterations, or the like) are set in C++ code in a much more demanding way.
Something stupid is done in the C++ code. While not so dramatically, I have seen C++ be slower than Python if you copy huge data structures without the need, resize large pictures multiple times when you can only do this once, create too many threads that starve for the same resource, and the like. Try to profile the C++ code. C++ allows you to write faster code, but only allows. The same fact of using C++ may not be enough.

